# A member of the System.Security.Claims namespace is not available?

Tags: c#, authentication, reference, .net-4.5, claims-based-identity

I am learning the new Claims-based Authentication methods in .NET 4.5, and am using a Console app to do so. According to MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsauthenticationmanager.aspx), ClaimsAuthenticationManager is a member of System.Security.Claims namespace. As you can see here, I am not getting this option. I have made sure the project is using .NET 4.5. I am missing something simple here... anyone have any suggestions?

[image: System.Security.Claims Intellisense options]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add a reference to `System.IdentityModel.dll`

You can see this in the documentation for [`ClaimsAuthenticationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsauthenticationmanager.aspx):

> Namespace:  System.Security.Claims
>
> Assembly:  System.IdentityModel (in System.IdentityModel.dll)

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I missed that... Thanks, Reed!